# import .sql file into database found on a server

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i am using phpmyadmin and i exported the database which I had locally. The exported file has an extension of .sql. I want to import the exported database into a database found online on the server. The server doesnt use phpmyadmin. I already connected to the database using SQL wave software however it doesn't offer the import feature like phpmyadmin does. After i installed mysqldumpler however i have the same problem. I cannot browse and import a .sql file. Can someone tell me how i can import the .sql file into my live database? Maybe a software you know or a command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the file to server. SSH into the server. Then you can load with the command line client:

```
mysql -u username -p dbname < path/to/file.sql
```

You will need to create the DB first.

Comment: OP can inject CREATE DATABASE/USE statements into sql file as well.Mysqldump have such options IMHO.